# Get month number of a week number in a year (Python)

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a year and a week number. I want to find out which month of the year does the week fall on.

For example, if `2018` is the year and `23` is the week. I want to calculate what month is the week number part of. The expected output for this example is `6` because the 23rd week in 2018 was in June.

I checked out the [Calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) module in the docs but I don't think there's a function for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Wher are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strptime()` method creates a datetime object from the given string.
If you pass it a string with the year, week and an arbitrary day, you will get the datetime object. Then you just extract the month.

```
import datetime

year = 2018
week = 23

date_string = f'{year}-W{week}-1'
month = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-W%W-%w").month

print(month) # 6
```

As a function:

```
def getMonth(year: int, week: int) -> int:
    """Return the month number in the given week in the given year."""
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{year}-W{week}-1', "%Y-W%W-%w").month

print(getMonth(2018, 23))
```